# How remove white spaces in Go

Tags: algorithm, go

I want remove spaces in String value, for example: "I d skd a efju N" to "IdskdaefjuN" and it's not working...

I tried using:

```
stringValue = strings.Replace(stringValue, " ", "", -1)
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //var String
    var stringValue string
    var originalValue string
    fmt.Printf("please, type some text:")
    //user input
    fmt.Scan(&stringValue)
    originalValue = stringValue
    //remove spaces
    stringValue = strings.Replace(stringValue, " ", "", -1)
    //set string to lower case
    stringValue = strings.ToLower(stringValue)
    //if contains substring "i", "a" and "n"
    if strings.Contains(stringValue, "i") && strings.Contains(stringValue, "a") && strings.Contains(stringValue, "n") {
        // if "i" is a prefix and "n" a suffix
        firstChar := strings.HasPrefix(stringValue, "i")
        lastChar := strings.HasSuffix(stringValue, "n")
        switch {
        //if is a prefix and suffix so Found
        case firstChar && lastChar:
            fmt.Printf("Found in %s", originalValue)
        //if isnt a prefix and suffix so Not Found
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Not Found in %s", originalValue)
        }
        //if there's no "i", "a" and "n"
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Not Found in %s", originalValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please make sure to construct a [mre]. I have a feeling that your example is not really minimal. Are you 100% sure it requires 27 lines to demonstrate your problem? Is it not maybe also possible in 26? Or even just 1?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: The question included a concise problem statement, "How remove white spaces in Go", input "I d skd a efju N" and expected output "IdskdaefjuN". It is clear.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm referring to user input, the method for removing whitespace, and final output, the code is complete just to make it easy to execute if someone really wants to understand the need or even realize an error that I didn't realize elsewhere in code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried running your code it wasn't reading from stdin properly using `fmt.Scan()`. If you replace it with a buffered reader that's reading from stdin it works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //var String
    var stringValue string
    var originalValue string
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Printf("please, type some text:")
    //user input
    stringValue, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
    stringValue = strings.TrimSuffix(stringValue, "\n")
    originalValue = stringValue
    //remove spaces
    stringValue = strings.ReplaceAll(stringValue, " ", "")
    //set string to lower case
    stringValue = strings.ToLower(stringValue)
    //if contains substring "i", "a" and "n"
    if strings.Contains(stringValue, "i") && strings.Contains(stringValue, "a") && strings.Contains(stringValue, "n") {
        // if "i" is a prefix and "n" a suffix
        firstChar := strings.HasPrefix(stringValue, "i")
        lastChar := strings.HasSuffix(stringValue, "n")
        switch {
        //if is a prefix and suffix so Found
        case firstChar && lastChar:
            fmt.Printf("Found in %s", originalValue)
        //if isnt a prefix and suffix so Not Found
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Not Found in %s", originalValue)
        }
        //if there's no "i", "a" and "n"
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Not Found in %s", originalValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code fails on Windows: `please, type some text:ian` `Not Found in ian`. On Windows, newline is `"\r\n"`. Use `bufio.Scanner` to read lines.

Comment: The question: "How remove white spaces in Go" Your code removes ASCII space. It does not remove [white space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Answer (score 4):

> How remove white spaces in Go

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func removeSpace(s string) string {
    rr := make([]rune, 0, len(s))
    for _, r := range s {
        if !unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            rr = append(rr, r)
        }
    }
    return string(rr)
}

func main() {
    s := "I d skd a efju N"
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = removeSpace(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/KoXZ24WXw7r

Output:

```
I d skd a efju N
IdskdaefjuN
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution? Because `string.ReplaceAll` also works in the playground. https://play.golang.org/p/dNYHn-AkVXf

Comment: @Jesse: The question asks: "How remove white spaces in Go?" See [Wikipedia: Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). I removed all Unicode White_Space characters. Also, see the Go standard library [strings.TrimSpace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) function.Your code (https://play.golang.org/p/dNYHn-AkVXf) only removes the ASCII space character. It does not remove all white space.

Answer (score 2):

I used this

```
func cleanSpaces(stringToClean string) string {
    result := strings.ReplaceAll(stringToClean, " ", "")
    return result
}
```

or

```
func cleanSpaces(stringToClean string) string {
    fields := strings.Fields(stringToClean)
    var result string
    for i := 0; i < len(fields); i++ {
       result += fields[i]
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
func main() {

    x := "       1    ,2,   3,4,6     -3   0, 7,   8,70   -9   0"
    x = strings.Replace(x, " ", "", -1)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

just replace whitespaces whith empty string see official [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) here